# CryptoPP vs PHP Base64 Encoding/Decoding

Tags: php, c++, encryption, public-key-encryption

I am trying to create a communication exchange between an application in PHP and C++ (CryptoPP).

I have the following code in PHP:

```
$in = "ALApfWG920ZFle/2r6CkXKXt+zG5tiw7Gw9ZLl1mKRNP9fyb12T92e9rTQF4JeapXSrZVBPyrGx52l4zmu+wr3u2EQW7CeYFbl9h8y5+xx0MPOL/1nyX6ENzo755klTy5AxcM9GMrpKt689i79ouuxceA2bCa0cpWMUv4c2dHN8nKaXDSyCW04dRglFds9CVb29JgQamFRc7H8yjPPdk/FIMDt3xCDOKjoT5VGM1v1Tsyo92qCSFW9N4xXqLr5NUO0hv5u+kVCg0P/gWbgSSNsflXjyqV+dBp3YzKdxHGQXbpl8IQvec95GjL60zQ7IS/rWOZg40+IrwbhvoWHUQIkM="
$out = base64_decode($decode)
```

It decodes the text and returns a binary `string`, as expected.
I am doing a similar command using CryptoPP in C++:

```
string out;
string in = "ALApfWG920ZFle/2r6CkXKXt+zG5tiw7Gw9ZLl1mKRNP9fyb12T92e9rTQF4JeapXSrZVBPyrGx52l4zmu+wr3u2EQW7CeYFbl9h8y5+xx0MPOL/1nyX6ENzo755klTy5AxcM9GMrpKt689i79ouuxceA2bCa0cpWMUv4c2dHN8nKaXDSyCW04dRglFds9CVb29JgQamFRc7H8yjPPdk/FIMDt3xCDOKjoT5VGM1v1Tsyo92qCSFW9N4xXqLr5NUO0hv5u+kVCg0P/gWbgSSNsflXjyqV+dBp3YzKdxHGQXbpl8IQvec95GjL60zQ7IS/rWOZg40+IrwbhvoWHUQIkM=";
CryptoPP::StringSource decryptor(in, true,
new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
new CryptoPP::StringSink(out)
    ));
```

However, when I inspect the `out` `string`, it is empty.

Could someone please pin-point what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run your code through Valgrind or ASAN?

Comment: Hi @KerrekSB, the C++ code is taken from the CryptoPP examples, so there's not much to check.  It has something to do with the input string but I'm not sure what it is.  It gives a result with other input strings.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot see the binary data because they start with a zero (\0).
\0 terminates a string, so you cannot see anything, but your data is stored.

Check:

```
out.size()
```

You can access your data with:

```
const char* data = out.c_str();
char* firstByte = data[0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much - displaying the string in the 'Immediate' window in VS did the trick.  I overlooked that the strings were at least partly visible in the debugger (when doing a mouse-over) since they didn't have the \0 terminator at the very beginning.